# UNIX - Handle terminale window state change

Tags: terminal, window, state

I would like to detect when the window running my CLI-program becomes active/inactive.

In concrete terms, my program receives regularly data from a server and displays them on the terminal window. Whenever new data are received I change the title of the window to notify the user. What I want to do is to reset the name of the window once he saw those new data.

I'm using python but I think I can go ahead if you have a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Some terminals such as `xterm` let you get that information as focus events. If you enable DEC mode 1004

```
CSI ? 1004 h
```

then you'll get focus in / focus out events sent as

```
CSI I      # focus in
CSI O      # focus out
```

Comment: I'm using gnome-terminal actually. And I'd like it to work on OSX too :/